# Not enough space on disk when installing second Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, centos, fedora

I have the following problem: I installed a CentOS version 6.4 on my new computer that has 1 TB of HDD and I decided to use all the available space in this disk.

Right now, I want to install a Fedora version 19 on this computer without erasing CentOS but when I try to install Fedora, there's this problem that says that there's no enough space, so I decided to use the fdisk utility from the terminal command line (in Fedora) to partition the space where CentOS is installed.

When I wanted to create a new partition with the `-n` option I only see the following range of sectors: 1953523712-1953525167 (I don't have enough space).

This is my table of available partitions:

```
Device      Boot    Start         End         Blocks     Id      System        
/dev/sda1       *      2048        1026047      512000     83        Linux
/dev/sda2             1026048     1953523711   976248832   8e       Linux LVM
```

I want to create a new partition with the space from the sda2, so I can install this Fedora version. The reason why I am installing these two RedHat distributions is because this is a project that I am currently working on for one of my university courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't resize your LVM with GParted, and AFAIK there's no easy-to-use GUI tool to do so.

Fortunately, you can handle *most* of what you need to handle within the LVM system. What you'll need to do is to use LVM tools (`system-config-lvm`, for instance, or the underlying text-based LVM tools) to shrink one or more logical volumes within the LVM partition. You can then point the CentOS installer at the existing volume group in the existing LVM partition and tell it to create its own logical volumes.

The snag in this is that I'm pretty sure that CentOS still needs its own `/boot` partition *outside* of the LVM setup. Thus, you'll need to do one of three things:

- Use another disk (even a USB flash drive) to hold the CentOS `/boot` partition. This is likely to be the easiest solution, but it will slow down the CentOS boot process, and it may be inconvenient as a long-term solution.
- Shrink your `/dev/sda1` partition to half its size to create half-sized `/boot` partitions for both Fedora and CentOS. I'm not sure if CentOS will complain about this, though; it might even refuse to install on such a small `/boot` partition. The smaller `/boot` partitions also pose a risk that you'll run out of space in the future.
- Shrink your LVM partition to make room for a new `/boot` partition. If you do this, I suppose you could shrink it even further and have two separate volume groups. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-resizing-partitions-2/index.html) I wrote a while ago for some information on resizing LVM physical volumes. This solution would produce the cleanest long-term solution, but it's likely to be the hardest in the short term.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I chose your last option.

Answer (score 4):

You must resize the current partition to make space for the new partition. Use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to resize/create partition instead of fdisk

Comment: GParted can't resize LVM partitions.